# Unable to use Hyper ledger Composer Playground Locally

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I followed the instrunctions in link - https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html

after the command:
`curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash`
successfully executed, the http://localhost:8080/ is still not available.

I am new to this please help what I am missing here.

## ERRORS :

I get the above error while running the `composer.sh`

```
# Create the channel
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx
2017-09-21 14:19:42.131 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-09-21 14:19:42.131 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-09-21 14:19:42.132 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: channel create configuration tx file not found open C:/Users/26266/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx: no such file or directory
Usage:
```

The above file is not available in the location, i checked manually

OR

or the below error

```
ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml down
.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/e/docker_H/composer-data/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/docker-compose.yml'
```

I checked, the above file is present in the location.

Comment: Can you supply the output from running the curl command please.

Comment: I have added the errors in the question, please guide.

Answer (score 3):

I see you are trying to run this on windows, unfortunately there are many issues with trying to get all parts of hyperledger composer running on windows (even in the git bash shell) so unfortunately windows is not a supported platform. I would recommend setting up a linux virtual machine using something like Virtualbox and running composer there.

Answer (score 0):

could you copy what output you get in your console when you run curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash

This script does not actually run things exactly "locally" in the machine rather in Docker containers.

It downloads all the required containers, the code needed and starts these containers as a daemon process. However, it expects you have a relatively new version of docker & docker-compose installed in the machine for it to work.

Try to run `./composer.sh` command in the folder where you ran the script for the first time. If you have requirements installed in your machine correctly this should work. Else just post the error you are getting. Exact URL you should be able to open is http://localhost:8080/editor

Comment: Getting an Error once I ran composer.sh

`ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml down
.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/e/docker_H/composer-data/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/docker-compose.yml'`

although this file in available in exactly the same path as it is checking.

I am running the commands in gitbash as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 7 and using Docker Toolbox, please run the command from a docker terminal.